# Can't access BIOS after running Boot-Repair

Tags: dual-boot, lenovo, bios

After updating from 18.04 to 20.04 I did not get the grub menu. I tried to fix that with Boot-Repair, but the only thing that did was to prevent me from accessing the BIOS.

I have a Lenovo laptop, and to get in to the BIOS you press the Novo button and then navigate the same was is if you were in the BIOS.

First there is a menu with 4 alternatives (if I remember correctly), one is BIOS and one is Boot Manager. I can use Boot Manager, but when I select BIOS it closes the that menu and does nothing more. I can't get on from there and have to turn off the laptop by holding down the power button.

Fixing grub was easy. I uncommented the line:

```
# GRUB_TERMINAL=console
```

Comment: Welcome, [what happens if you go to the recovery option](https://support.lenovo.com/us/en/solutions/HT062552)?

Comment: I have chatted with the help at Lenovo and one tip was to start Windows 10 and restart while holding the shift button. The problem with that is that when I restart from Windows it starts Ubuntu. Wait, now when the grub is working again I might have a chance to restart Windows. I will give it a shot and come back here.

Comment: Well it still don't work to get in to the BIOS that way. I actually don't need the BIOS right now and I am waiting for an answer from Boot repair so I let this brew for a while, When I get the BIOS working I will tell You how I did.

Comment: How do I do to get a notification to my mail when there is an answer on this thread.

Comment: Last entry in grub menu is to get into your UEFI. And if you have UEFI fast boot on, you do not have time to press any key. Fast boot assumes you have made no system changes and immediately boots whatever configuration you have. That is different setting than Windows fast start up which also needs to be off. If fast boot on, often "Cold Boot" or full power down reverts to a normal boot giving time to press key to get into UEFI settings.

Comment: I have tried that last entry. It does exactly as when I choose BIOS in the Novo button menu. Nothing happens.

Comment: Your BIOS is a function of your motherboard's firmware. What's going on with your operating systems is irrelevant to you being able to access your firmware settings. If you can't figure it out pressing random keys, I suggest that you consult with the documentation for your motherboard. Ubuntu or any other OS can't prevent you from accessing the BIOS.

Comment: Well, it might be a unusual coincident that it happened to me twice. I have used Boot repair twice and twice I have had problems with the BIOS.

Comment: I got a mail with this subject "1 new item in your Stack Exchange inbox". Is that from here? When I get a new comment on the thread?

Comment: @krassegrand [This may help you regarding your last comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/298906/control-the-types-of-email-you-receive-via-our-new-email-settings-feature).